# Can I have functors in C?

Tags: c++, c

Can I have functors in C? I mean for example in C++ I can do:

```
struct Rules
{

    operator()(/*maybe some args*/)
    {
    }
};
```

Some (fictitious) algorithm:

```
int sort(iter beg, iter end, Rules);
```

Can I do identically in C?

Comment: Depends on what exactly you mean by "functor" and "identically"; you should really be more precise about what you want to ask. Obviously you can't do it exactly like in your question since C has no classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really.  At best, you could do something like:

```
int sort(iter a, iter b, bool (*cmp)(iter a, iter b, void *), void *p_state)
{
    ...
    cmp(a, b, p_state);
}


bool func(iter a, iter b, void *p_state)
{
    type_t *p_type = (type_t *)p_state;
    ...
}


type_t state;
...
sort(a, b, func, &state);
```

This allows you to give the function state, albeit manually.

You may be able to hide some of the clunkiness behind macros, but beware macros!

Answer (score 7):

Not identically, no. C doesn't support member functions for structures, nor operator overloading.

You can, however, pass and store function pointers. You could make your `sort` take a structure with a comparison function pointer, and call the passed function. For an example, see `qsort` in the C standard library...

```
qsort(void *base, size_t nel, size_t width, int (*compar)(const void *, const void *));
```

that last parameter is a sorting comparison function pointer. You could create a structure such as...

```
struct Rules_t
{
  int (*comparisonRule)(const void *, const void *);
} Rules;
```

then pass instances of this structure around calling, e.g. `myRules->comparisonRule(a, b)`.

Comment: This doesn't emulate the ability of functors to have state.

Comment: Not directly, no. As I said, C doesn't support functions. However, you can, in the same structure, have state. You will need to pass the structure instance to the function being called.

Answer (score 0):

In C++ `struct` is nothing but `public class`. This is not the case in C.